# Can I use altair/vega lookup tables to select a row that's not a join field (ie using data + metadata files)?

Tags: altair, vega-lite

How can I create an altair/vega line chart from data and metadata tables where the data table is too large to fit in memory? AKA Can I use lookup to select a row that's not a join field

For simplicity, I'm showing it as if it were Altair+Pandas, but the actual data table is enormous, so I expect to load them from json or csv.

I have a data table something like:

```
data = pd.DataFrame([
        ('A', 0.5, 0.45, 0.2, 0.25, 0.55, 0.45, 0.4, 0),
        ('B', 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0, 0.15, 0.25, 0.1, 0),
        ('C', 0.3, 0.25, 0.7, 0.75, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 1),
    ],
    columns = ('gene', 's1r1t1', 's1r2t1', 's1r1t2', 's1r2t2', 's2r1t1', 's2r2t1', 's2r2t1', 's2r2t2'),
).set_index('gene')
```

(in reality, with 50K rows)

with corresponding metadata like:

```
md = pd.DataFrame([
        ('s1r1t1', 1, 1, 1),
        ('s1r2t1', 1, 2, 1),
        ('s1r1t2', 1, 1, 2),
        ('s1r2t2', 1, 2, 2),
        ('s2r1t1', 2, 1, 1),
        ('s2r2t1', 2, 2, 1),
        ('s2r2t1', 2, 1, 2),
        ('s2r2t2', 2, 2, 2),
    ],
    columns = ('sample', 'subject', 'replicate', 'timepoint'),
).set_index('sample')
```

(in reality, with 4 replicates, 6 timepoints, and 5 experimental conditions)

and want to show graphs of the expression levels of a single gene by timepoint.

For a tiny set like this, I can graph it like:

```
data_melt = data.reset_index().melt(
    id_vars='gene',
    var_name='sample',
)

merged = pd.merge( 
    left=md.reset_index(), 
    right=data_melt, 
    left_on='sample',
    right_on='sample',
    
)

dropdown = alt.selection_single(
    fields=['gene'], 
    bind=alt.binding_select(options=data.index.to_list()),
    name='gene',
    init={'gene': data.index[0]}
)

alt.Chart(
    merged
).mark_line(
).encode(
    x='timepoint:O',
    y='mean(value):Q'
).add_selection(
    dropdown
).transform_filter(
    dropdown
)
```

However, I'd like some way to only load a small fraction (ideally a single gene) from the data table.
I have been trying methods like:

```
# Create files and serve them via proxy
data_fname = 'data.csv'
data.to_csv(data_fname)
md_fname =  'metadata.csv'
md.to_csv('metadata.csv')
alt.data_transformers.enable('data_server')

# Build chart
lookup = alt.LookupData(
    data=data_fname,
    key='gene',
    fields=md.index.to_list(),
)

c = alt.Chart(md_fname).mark_point().encode(
    x='timepoint:O',
    y='gene:Q'
).add_selection(
    dropdown
).transform_filter(
    dropdown
).transform_lookup(
    from_=lookup,
    lookup='gene', 
)
```

But have clearly messed up the lookup, since the chart doesn't show anything, whether in my devel notebook, or in an exported HTML on my web-server, with the urls fixed in the JSON to point to the actual files.

Is this possible, and if so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no built-in way to do dynamic data loading with Altair or Vega-Lite, but there are efforts underway to handle larger datasets and to push computations into a database backend. See https://github.com/vega/scalable-vega for details.